# Mounting error trying to access the drives in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: filesystem, drive

While trying to mount the drive I get the error below and the drive is not mounted.

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ubuntu/B840AE6C40AE30D4: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/media/sukhen/B840AE6C40AE30D4"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). 
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. 
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted 
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. 
Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting),
or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem and I fixed it. I have dual booted my system in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. So if you too have a dual boot system, this is how to do it :

- Boot into windows
- Search for and open **Power options** in the Start Menu
- Click **Choose what the power buttons do** on the left side of the window
- Click **Change settings that are currently unavailable**.
- Under **shutdown settings** you will see "Turn on fast startup(recommended)"
- **Disable** it and click **Save changes**.

[image: Screenshot: How to disable fast boot in Windows] 
 Done!

- Now boot back into Ubuntu, you will be able to mount the drive as well as access it with both Windows and Ubuntu

However this will increase the boot time of windows but change is not significant and necessary too if you want dual booted system. It worked for me and I hope, this works in your case too.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Windows and shut it down fully. That message claims it's in hibernation mode, or some equivalent. I've seen this error before multiple times, so I assume that is the solution.

> ***Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)***